# Eclipse Vaadin Widgetset compile heap size problem

Tags: eclipse, vaadin8

While compiling vaadin widgetset on my eclipse, i get this error.

i see some posts that say we can change heap space size in vaadin plugin but there is no settings like this on my eclipse. ([My plugin settings](https://vgy.me/0iyOCR.png))([Related Post](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/16824499/vaadin-widgetset-compilation-outofmemoryerror-eclipse))

while compiling widgetset, vaadin plugin runs a command and it sets -Xss8M and -Xmx512M.

Is there any way to change this settings?

Error:

```
Executing compiler with command line:
 C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin\java.exe -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xss8M -Xmx512M -classpath C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;D:/Projects/jguar_GIT_Set/jvhr/LbsVPCorporatePortal/src;D:/Projects/jguar_GIT_Set/jvhr/LbsVPCorporatePortal/build/classes;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.vaadin/vaadin-server/jars/vaadin-server-8.4.3.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.vaadin/vaadin-sass-compiler/jars/vaadin-sass-compiler-0.9.13.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.w3c.css/sac/jars/sac-1.3.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.vaadin.external.flute/flute/jars/flute-1.3.0.gg2.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.vaadin/vaadin-shared/jars/vaadin-shared-8.4.3.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.jsoup/jsoup/jars/jsoup-1.11.2.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.vaadin.external/gentyref/jars/gentyref-1.2.0.vaadin1.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.vaadin/vaadin-themes/jars/vaadin-themes-8.4.3.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.github.appreciated/material/jars/material-1.1.7.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.vaadin.addons/fontawesomelabel/jars/fontawesomelabel-1.4.0.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.vaadin.addons/popupbutton/jars/popupbutton-3.0.0.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.vaadin.blackbluegl/calendar-component/jars/calendar-component-2.0-BETA4.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.vaadin.addon/tableexport-for-vaadin/jars/tableexport-for-vaadin-1.8.0.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.github.appreciated/app-layout-addon/jars/app-layout-addon-0.9.20.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.ocpsoft.prettytime/prettytime/bundles/prettytime-4.0.1.Final.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.lbs.vaadin.addons/lbs-vaadin-datetimerangepicker/jars/lbs-vaadin-datetimerangepicker-1.0.0.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.tltv.gantt/gantt-addon/jars/gantt-addon-1.0.3.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.vaadin/vaadin-client-compiled/jars/vaadin-client-compiled-8.4.3.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.google.guava/guava/bundles/guava-18.0.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.wcs.wcslib/wcslib-vaadin-widget-recaptcha/jars/wcslib-vaadin-widget-recaptcha-2.0.3.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.jarektoro/responsive-layout/bundles/responsive-layout-2.1.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.vaadin.addons/inputmask/jars/inputmask-1.0.2.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.vaadin/vaadin-client/jars/vaadin-client-8.4.3.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.google.gwt/gwt-elemental/jars/gwt-elemental-2.8.2.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.google.gwt/gwt-user/jars/gwt-user-2.8.2.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.google.jsinterop/jsinterop-annotations/jars/jsinterop-annotations-1.0.2-sources.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.vaadin/vaadin-client-compiler/jars/vaadin-client-compiler-8.4.3.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/jars/gwt-dev-2.8.2.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/jars/jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.google.code.gson/gson/jars/gson-2.6.2.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.ow2.asm/asm/jars/asm-5.0.3.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.ow2.asm/asm-util/jars/asm-util-5.0.3.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.ow2.asm/asm-tree/jars/asm-tree-5.0.3.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.ow2.asm/asm-commons/jars/asm-commons-5.0.3.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/colt/colt/jars/colt-1.2.0.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/ant/ant/jars/ant-1.6.5.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/commons-collections/commons-collections/jars/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/commons-io/commons-io/jars/commons-io-2.4.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.ibm.icu/icu4j/jars/icu4j-50.1.1.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/tapestry/tapestry/jars/tapestry-4.0.2.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit/jars/htmlunit-2.19.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/xalan/xalan/jars/xalan-2.7.2.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/xalan/serializer/jars/serializer-2.7.2.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/jars/commons-lang3-3.4.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/jars/httpclient-4.5.1.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/jars/httpcore-4.4.3.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/commons-logging/commons-logging/jars/commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/commons-codec/commons-codec/jars/commons-codec-1.5.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/jars/httpmime-4.5.1.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit-core-js/jars/htmlunit-core-js-2.17.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/xerces/xercesImpl/jars/xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/xml-apis/xml-apis/jars/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/net.sourceforge.nekohtml/nekohtml/jars/nekohtml-1.9.22.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/net.sourceforge.cssparser/cssparser/jars/cssparser-0.9.18.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/websocket-client/jars/websocket-client-9.2.13.v20150730.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util/jars/jetty-util-9.2.9.v20150224.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-io/jars/jetty-io-9.2.14.v20151106.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/websocket-common/jars/websocket-common-9.2.14.v20151106.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/websocket-api/jars/websocket-api-9.2.14.v20151106.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-webapp/jars/jetty-webapp-9.2.9.v20150224.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-xml/jars/jetty-xml-9.2.14.v20151106.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-servlet/jars/jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-security/jars/jetty-security-9.2.14.v20151106.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server/jars/jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-http/jars/jetty-http-9.2.14.v20151106.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-servlets/jars/jetty-servlets-9.2.9.v20150224.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-continuation/jars/jetty-continuation-9.2.14.v20151106.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-annotations/jars/jetty-annotations-9.2.14.v20151106.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-plus/jars/jetty-plus-9.2.14.v20151106.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-jndi/jars/jetty-jndi-9.2.14.v20151106.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api/jars/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty/apache-jsp/jars/apache-jsp-9.2.14.v20151106.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain/jetty-schemas/jars/jetty-schemas-3.1.M0.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.mortbay.jasper/apache-jsp/jars/apache-jsp-8.0.9.M3.jar;C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.mortbay.jasper/apache-el/jars/apache-el-8.0.9.M3.jar;D:/Projects/jguar_GIT_Set/jvhr/LbsVPCorporatePortal/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/LbsApplicationInfo.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/resources.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/rt.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/jsse.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/jce.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/charsets.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/jfr.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/ext/access-bridge-64.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/ext/dnsns.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/ext/jaccess.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/ext/localedata.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/ext/nashorn.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/ext/sunec.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/ext/zipfs.jar -Dgwt.persistentunitcachedir=C:\Users\BEKIR~1.MAV\AppData\Local\Temp\widgetset_com.lbs.corporate.widgetset.LbsVPCorporatePortalWidgetset29dd9ad9-ed25-4c1a-bc70-9941f577cf8f com.vaadin.tools.WidgetsetCompiler -war WebContent/VAADIN/widgetsets -deploy C:\Users\BEKIR~1.MAV\AppData\Local\Temp\widgetset_com.lbs.corporate.widgetset.LbsVPCorporatePortalWidgetset29dd9ad9-ed25-4c1a-bc70-9941f577cf8f -extra C:\Users\BEKIR~1.MAV\AppData\Local\Temp\widgetset_com.lbs.corporate.widgetset.LbsVPCorporatePortalWidgetset29dd9ad9-ed25-4c1a-bc70-9941f577cf8f -localWorkers 8 -logLevel INFO com.lbs.corporate.widgetset.LbsVPCorporatePortalWidgetset
Updating GWT module description file...
Widgetsets found from classpath:
    org.vaadin.hene.popupbutton.widgetset.PopupbuttonWidgetset in jar:file:C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.vaadin.addons/popupbutton/jars/popupbutton-3.0.0.jar!/
    com.lbs.vaadin.addons.datetimerangepicker.WidgetSet in jar:file:C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.lbs.vaadin.addons/lbs-vaadin-datetimerangepicker/jars/lbs-vaadin-datetimerangepicker-1.0.0.jar!/
    org.vaadin.inputmask.WidgetSet in jar:file:C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.vaadin.addons/inputmask/jars/inputmask-1.0.2.jar!/
    org.vaadin.addon.calendar.WidgetSet in jar:file:C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.vaadin.blackbluegl/calendar-component/jars/calendar-component-2.0-BETA4.jar!/
    com.lbs.corporate.widgetset.LbsVPCorporatePortalWidgetset in file:/D:/Projects/jguar_GIT_Set/jvhr/LbsVPCorporatePortal/src
    org.tltv.gantt.WidgetSet in jar:file:C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.tltv.gantt/gantt-addon/jars/gantt-addon-1.0.3.jar!/
    com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet in jar:file:C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.vaadin/vaadin-client/jars/vaadin-client-8.4.3.jar!/
Addon styles found from classpath:
    VAADIN/addons/font-awesome-label/font-awesome.scss in jar:file:C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.vaadin.addons/fontawesomelabel/jars/fontawesomelabel-1.4.0.jar!/
    VAADIN/addons/calendar/calendar-addon.scss in jar:file:C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.vaadin.blackbluegl/calendar-component/jars/calendar-component-2.0-BETA4.jar!/
    VAADIN/addons/app-layout/app-layout.scss in jar:file:C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/com.github.appreciated/app-layout-addon/jars/app-layout-addon-0.9.20.jar!/
    VAADIN/addons/gantt/gantt.scss in jar:file:C:/Users/bekir.mavus/.ivy2/cache/org.tltv.gantt/gantt-addon/jars/gantt-addon-1.0.3.jar!/

Search took 16ms
Done.
Starting GWT compiler
Oca 16, 2019 9:17:35 AM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
Compiling module com.lbs.corporate.widgetset.LbsVPCorporatePortalWidgetset
Oca 16, 2019 9:18:33 AM com.vaadin.tools.WidgetsetCompiler lambda$main$0
SEVERE: Widgetset compilation failed
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtUtil.signature(JdtUtil.java:356)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.ReferenceMapper.setMethod(ReferenceMapper.java:192)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder.createMethod(GwtAstBuilder.java:4197)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder.createMembers(GwtAstBuilder.java:4086)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder.processImpl(GwtAstBuilder.java:3929)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder.process(GwtAstBuilder.java:3971)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater$UnitProcessorImpl.process(CompilationStateBuilder.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler$CompilerImpl.process(JdtCompiler.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.processCompiledUnits(Compiler.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:458)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.doCompile(JdtCompiler.java:1040)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:325)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:548)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:479)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:465)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:423)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:222)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:202)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:143)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:204)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:155)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:144)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:118)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:125)
    at com.vaadin.tools.WidgetsetCompiler.lambda$main$0(WidgetsetCompiler.java:78)
    at com.vaadin.tools.WidgetsetCompiler$$Lambda$1/511754216.run(Unknown Source)

Widgetset compilation finished
```

Comment: Solved. not in eclipse prefrences. At project proporties there is a vaadin section and enables to set project based settings. I set "Additional JVM parameters" to -Xmx2048M